# Did I miss my chance to have a ship's doctor?

Tags: mass-effect-3

So I've been playing the "Why can't I click the Save BILLIONS option?" greyed-out paragon score dance with Dr. Michel and I finally have my paragon score above the first dash on the squad screen.

Since I was in the citadel anyway to enable access for the students and instructors of Grissom Academy (I just finished rescuing them) I thought I'd pop into the med bay and see if she wants to join my band of intergalactic misfits now ... and she's nowhere to be found!?!

Ashley's a spectre now and out of the med bay, so I can understand Michel not needing to stand in the lobby caring for the visitors Ash is getting but where did she go??  Did she finally make up her mind to come with me, give 2 weeks notice and decide to use up her banked vacation time or what??  I'm doctorless and now wondering if I've waited too long club her over the head and drag her back to the ship.

Did I miss my chance to have a ship's doctor?  If not, who is going to step up?  If so, what's the ultimate consequence of it?

> It's clear that Mordin can't help out since he died ...

Comment: Good because that doesn't happen. You're 100% sure she isn't around? I had to wait around like you did but I found her after trying like 3 times and waiting until the Krogran part of the plot.

Comment: I've combed the station.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MtkK3eijBso#t=12

Comment: She should only be in the hospital, in that first room out of the elevator.

Comment: Have you checked in the crew quarters of your ship? Chakwas heads down there sometimes.

Comment: Chakwas is back in R&D ... I turned her down to persue Michel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, you may have waited too long, and you will need to find someone else, I have seen this happen before, no fix as far as I know.

Comment: Source? Who might "someone else" be if not one of the two initial choices?

Comment: Oooh! I know this one! Doctor Chakwas is the answer, as the answer below me states.

Comment: @Portali5t As the comment below the answer below says, I told her to go to R&D ... so how can I possibly retrieve her?

Comment: Well, you can't. Ooops, well it is too late now but you can use them if they aren't sent off to R&D

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you waited too long, but you haven't lost your chance to have a doctor, you'll just have to stick with Dr. Chakwas.

Comment: How can I recover Dr. Chakwas when I already sent her off to R&D?